# Grid spacing issue in IE8/9 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've encountered a weird situation where the first `<dl>` element has a width twice as large as the others, but only in IE. This causes gaps to appear in this photo grid layout.

Example: http://user45201.vs.easily.co.uk/?page_id=109

Works fine in Chrome/FF/IE7 but has weird spacing in IE8 & IE9.

Comment: What "first element"?  Can you describe the problem a little better and provide a scaled down/isolated sample?

Comment: Each photo in the grid is wrapped in a '<dl>' element. If you view this grid in IE8 or 9, the spacing behaves strangely. I could copy an example here but if you view the page in IE8 or 9 it is immediately evident

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS Reset? This would help to ensure that basic page elements look the same across all browsers, rather than picking up any odd differences between them in the default rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like part of the trouble is the floating elements within the non floating parent. I added a float left to the parent container and that fixed it. Since you are using width 33% and trying to apply spacing onto the elements I added the box-sizing property so the images won't jump to the next line. Hope this helps.

```
#gallery-1 {
    float:left;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-item {
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    width: 33%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#gallery-1 .gallery-icon{
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```